# kendo diagram add circle on click

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to draw circle diagram on html button click (would prefer it on kendo diagram toolbar which is not working too), the addShape method seems to be working fine without any errors, but the diagram doesn't show up on the page.
However the circle is drawn with no issues on initial kendo diagram load.

```js
$(document).ready(createDiagram);

function createDiagram() {
  $("#diagram").kendoDiagram({
    shapes: [{
        type: 'circle',
        fill: {
          color: 'blue'
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'rectangle'
      }
    ],
    shapeDefaults: {
      editable: {
        tools: ["createShape", "delete", "rotateClockwise", "rotateAnticlockwise"]
      }
    },
    connectionDefaults: {
      stroke: {
        color: "#979797",
        width: 1
      },
      type: "polyline",
      startCap: "FilledCircle",
      endCap: "ArrowEnd"
    },
    editable: {
      tools: ["createShape", "delete", "rotateClockwise", "rotateAnticlockwise"]
    }
  });
  $("#diagram").getKendoDiagram().layout();
}

function drawCircle() {  
  var diagram = $("#diagram").getKendoDiagram();

  /*diagram.addShape(new kendo.dataviz.diagram.Point(100, 220), {
    background: "red"
  });*/
  diagram.addShape(new kendo.dataviz.diagram.Circle({
    radius: 600,
    stroke: {
      width: 5,
      color: "#586477"
    },
    fill: "#e8eff7"
  }));  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />
<base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/diagram/events">


<input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Circle" onclick="drawCircle();" />
<div id="diagram"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be occurring as you have might have put your JS code after your HTML. i.e after the `</body>` tag ends. This might be leading to problems.

In this working [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/wmtu4j47/), I have placed all the JS code into the `<head>` tag and now the function `dramCircle()` is being called successfully.